# GitHub PR: Update with rebase

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I need to update my feature branch with updates from the base branch. There's an option "Update with rebase" in GitHub PR for my feature branch.

What exactly will happen on base and my feature branches if I click that option?

The description of the option and information I could find on the internet didn't make it clear to me. I can't test it either as I'm afraid to mess things up.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly will happen on base and my feature branches if I click that option?

- **Base branch (`dev`)**: nothing.
- **Your feature branch**: will be rebased.

> I can't test it either as I'm afraid to mess things up.

No need to worry, both options in the GitHub UI only modify your own feature branch, and like most things in Git, it's generally pretty easy to fix things if you mess up. You can also test them both locally, and when you're done playing around you can blow away your local branch and replace it with the server version:

```
git fetch
git reset --hard @{u} # replace local branch with remote tracking branch

# Note that is the same as
git reset --hard origin/my-feature-branch
```

**What's the difference between the merge and rebase options?**

Suppose you created a branch called `feature` a few days ago from `dev`. At that moment of creation the two branches are identical. (i.e., they are both pointing to the same commit ID). Now, you wish to create a PR to merge `feature` into `dev`, and in the last few days there are 20 more commits on `dev` that aren't "in" (aka "reachable by") `feature`. If you decide you'd like to update your branch with the latest version of `dev` to include those 20 missing commits, you have two options:

1. Merge `dev` *into* `feature`. From the command line you could do this yourself with:

```
git fetch # get the latest version of origin/dev
git switch feature
git merge origin/dev
git push
```

This will modify your branch by adding a new merge commit to your branch which merges the 20 new commits on `dev` into your branch.

2. Rebase `feature` *onto* `dev`. From the command line you could do this yourself with:

```
git fetch # get the latest version of origin/dev
git rebase origin/dev feature
git push --force-with-lease
```

This will modify your branch by completely rewriting it, so that it looks like you created it today from the current version of `dev`, and then added each of your commits "on top" of this new branch. This will appear to be "cleaner" and will not have a new merge commit in its history. Note- the Author datetime and username of your commits will not change; only the Committer datetime and usernames will change- and they will change to be you, and right now. When viewing the history of a rebased branch, it's common to see your commits at the top with older dates than the commits underneath it.

Notes:

1. The end *state* of your branch should be the same whether you merge or rebase, but the graphical history will be different.
2. Anytime you rewrite your branch (e.g. rebase or amend a commit), you must force push it instead of a regular push.
3. Whether you do the merge/rebase locally, or let GitHub do it for you, the end result should be the same.
4. If you are unhappy with the result, you can always fix it up locally and force push the branch back out.
5. It's possible to have conflicts with both merge and rebase, and in some cases you may need to abort and resolve them locally instead of in the GitHub UI.

Answer (score 1):

The same as what you would do locally by running `git rebase origin/dev` and then force push.

Make sure to run `git fetch` first to have the latest version for `origin/dev`.

Answer (score 0):

In few words:

It will rewrite your branch and put the `dev` branch commits before your `feature` commits. Even if your `feature` commits were made before the `dev` ones.